# Runtime comparison of types for lifting polymorphic data structures into GADTs

Tags: haskell, gadt

Suppose we define a GADT for comparison of types:

```
data EQT a b where
  Witness :: EQT a a
```

Is it then possible to declare a function **eqt** with the following type signature:

```
eqt :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> b -> Maybe (EQT a b)
```

...such that **eqt x y** evaluates to **Just Witness** if **typeOf x == typeOf y** --- and otherwise to **Nothing**?

The function **eqt** would make it possible to lift ordinary polymorphic data structures into GADTs.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is. Here's one way:

First, the type-equality type.

```
data EQ :: * -> * -> * where
  Refl :: EQ a a  -- is an old traditional name for this constructor
  deriving Typeable
```

Note that it can itself be made an instance of Typeable. That's the key.
Now I just need to get my hands on the Refl I need, like this.

```
refl :: a -> EQ a a
refl _ = Refl
```

And now I can try to turn (Refl :: Eq a a) into something of type (Eq a b)
by using Data.Typeable's cast operator. That will work just when a and b
are equal!

```
eq :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> b -> Maybe (EQ a b)
eq a _ = cast (refl a)
```

The hard work has already been done.

More variations on this theme can be found in the Data.Witness library,
but the Data.Typeable cast operator is all you need for this job. It's
cheating, of course, but safely packaged cheating.

Comment: Safely packaged so long as nobody made an incorrect `Data.Typeable` instance on something. (`deriving Typeable` is always safe.)

Comment: Note that these days `eq` is available in the `Data.Typeable` module as [`eqT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:eqT)